# Hidden the overflow part in 2 column

Tags: html, css

I have 3 images and I want to arrange them in 2 columns, one column for 1 image and the other for 2 images. The problem is 2 columns have different heights. And I want to hide the overflow part of the taller column.  The picture below shows that.

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```css
.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.section-features img {
  width: 100%;
}

.section-features .span-1-of-3 {
  width: 33.3%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.section-features .span-2-of-3 {
  width: 66.6%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-features">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
      <a href="#"><img src="resources/img/modern-brownstone.jpeg" alt="Mordern Brownstone Picture"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#"><img src="resources/img/intimate-setting.jpg" alt="An Intimate Setting"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#"><img src="resources/img/edgy-classic.jpg" alt="Edge Classic"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the portion of the images in the `.span-2-of-3` and `.span-1-of-3` classes. Do not divide the images from 100% because you have added some padding, therefore reduce the padding from the total width. Just to be sure, add   `overflow: hidden;` in the `.section-features img`.

```css
.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.section-features img {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.section-features .span-1-of-3 {
  width: 30%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  float: right;
}

.section-features .span-2-of-3 {
  width: 60%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-features">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/07/22/2057921811589a1.jpg" alt="Mordern Brownstone Picture"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/07/22/2057921811589a1.jpg" alt="An Intimate Setting"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/07/22/2057921811589a1.jpg" alt="Edge Classic"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is that give a `max-height` to your section and set `overflow:hidden` that will do. Below is a demo for the same.

```css
section {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img1 {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
}

.img2 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
 div {
 margin:5px;
}
.img3 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="img1">

  </div>
  <div class="conatiner">
    <div class="img2">

    </div>
    <div class="img3">

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It work, but when i reduce the width of the browser, following the height of the image also reduced. And the problem occurs again when the height of the image is smaller than max-height.

Comment: yes because you have have width in % and when you reduce the width of browser the width of image also changes as it in % so does the height to maintain the aspect ratio of image.

Comment: It seems i have to fix my width in pixel. But that not good for a responsive design. Is there any better solution? I think I may add some javascript code to equal height of column A and B. Or maybe cut my image in photoshop.

Comment: one possible solution will be you can set the image as `background-image` in that way it will not crop the image and adjust according to width of your div/element to which you set the image as background

Answer (score 0):

```css
.section-features .row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
}
.col.span-2-of-3 {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #f00;
}
.col.span-1-of-3 {
    width: 30%;
}
.col.span-1-of-3 .row {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100px;
}
.col.span-1-of-3 .row:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-features">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <div class="row">
                <a href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <a href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```